# Memory usage problems on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ram

It's a few months that my pc is running Ubuntu 20.10 and I have a problem: every two/three hours my pc run out of memory and all my attemps to run oom killer fails in many cases, the problem is that when I run some games and I open anything like Chrome, my pc run out of memory. I want a solution to this because i can't play games or processes that use an high amount of ram, Is there any permanent solution?

Consider that my pc has 8gb of ram and running `top` on my terminal show how my games ends all the memory.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable reason to upgrade your RAM or, barring that, increasing the amount of swap space that is available. While more swap is not always the answer, it can help alleviate some of the challenges an OS can face when working with applications that demand a great deal of physical memory.

Comment: The swap is 2gb

Comment: This is a suboptimal amount when working with memory-intensive applications. You may wish to increase it to a value between 8 and 24GB, depending on the types of games/applications you run most often.

Comment: courrently i am able to limit the amount of ram of some of the games by changing some settings but the same games runs on Windows without any problem

Comment: Is the same game that works in Windows also written to work in Linux natively without emulation?  Sometimes trying to force a game that is not written to work in Linux natively can also cause memory leaks.

Comment: The game is made in java, so there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: Maybe when running your game and launching Chrome (which is a known memory killer) try running `sudo inxi -t m10` to show the top 10 memory usage apps.

Comment: 2G /swapfile isn't enough for 8G RAM and large apps. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's increase your 2G /swapfile to 4G...

**Note**: Ultimately you may need to add more RAM.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: Well now my computer is dead and top is showing me that the swap is full so I think increasing maybe be the solution

Comment: Ok after some hours, no crashes, it is running without any problem

Comment: Ok no it's crashed right now

Comment: @Ric3cir121 Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. How many hours had it been running before crash?

Comment: @Ric3cir121 Do `cat /var/log/syslog` and paste that output at paste.ubuntu.com and give me the URL and I'll take a look. What local time did it crash?

Comment: @Ric3cir121 Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: @Ric3cir121 Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness`

Comment: oh I am sorry for not giving any answer to the question, but it has been a few days that my computer is running without any crash, I think I don't need anymore to make my pc better for now as I think I will never run programs that require more resources, so, still thanks for your help